# project path use as domain in nginx -tomcat

Tags: tomcat, nginx

spring java project run in my server. I added new domain, it works, however when click a link it goes to http://127.0.0.1:8081/ instead of example.com

```
server {
  listen          80;

  server_name     www.example.com example.com;
      root            /opt/appserv/travel_server/webapps/example;

location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {
        root /opt/appserv/travel_server/webapps/example/;
        expires 30d;
    }

  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/example;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    server {
  listen          80;

  server_name     www.example.com example.com
  #server_name_in_redirect off;
  root            /opt/appserv/travel_server/webapps/example;

location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {
        root /opt/appserv/travel_server/webapps/example/;
        expires 30d;
    }

 location ~* ^/(.*) {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/example/$1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Now, it does not get parameters. example.com/path?pId=13